# How can I install this package?

Tags: miktex, windows

[This package](https://miktex.org/packages/ieeetran) does not show up in the miktex package manager (win8.1 sharelatex repo). How can I install it? Do I need a different repo? If so, which?

Comment: I see it at https://miktex.org/packages/ieeetran

Comment: @egreg yes, in a web browser it shows up but not in the package manager.

Comment: I see it in my package manager. Maybe synchonise the repositories (menu `repository` of M.P.M.)?